# Error while unmarshalling with JAXB classes usage

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I've got generated JAXB classes from following xsd schema:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="MeetUpData">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SessionData">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="Date" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="Quantity" type="xs:int" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="Theme" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="Location" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now I'm trying to unmarshall following XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MeetUpData>
    <location>3</location>
    <name>2</name>
    <sessionsData>
        <date>345</date>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <theme>Windows</theme>
    </sessionsData>
    <sessionsData>
        <date>3</date>
        <quantity>7</quantity>
        <theme>9</theme>
    </sessionsData>
</MeetUpData>
```

by the following piece of code:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MeetUp.class);
            Unmarshaller ums = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            meetUpData = (MeetUpData) ums.unmarshal(new FileInputStream("src\\com\\bases\\java\\InitialXML.xml"));
            System.out.println("Info: " + meetUpData.toString());
```

But I get a bunch of errors:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"MeetUpData"). Expected elements are (none)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
    ....
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Your XML does not match the schema. For example, `Location` should be an attribute on the `MeetUpData` element. In your XML you have a separate `location` element instead. The same for `Name` / `name`. Also, in XML you have a `sessionsData` element while in the XSD it is named `SessionData`, and there are more mistakes. Make sure your XML matches your XSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your java classes look like, but by the error message you didn't annotate the root class with @XMLRootElement.

I've changed the instantiation of JAXB using MeetUpData class, and annotating it with @XMLRootElement.

Here are the functional sources

**MeetUpData.class**:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class MeetUpData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String location;
    String name;
    List<SessionData> sessionsData;

    public MeetUpData() {
        super();
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<SessionData> getSessionsData() {
        return sessionsData;
    }

    public void setSessionsData(List<SessionData> sessionsData) {
        this.sessionsData = sessionsData;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MeetUpData [location=" + location + ", name=" + name + ", sessionData=" + sessionsData + "]";
    }

}
```

**Code to unmarshall**:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MeetUpData.class);
Unmarshaller ums = jc.createUnmarshaller();
MeetUpData meetUpData = (MeetUpData) ums.unmarshal(new FileInputStream(
               "src\\com\\bases\\java\\InitialXML.xml"));
System.out.println("Info: " + meetUpData.toString());
```

In addition, you'll need to change "MeetUpData" tag in yout XML to start with lower case 'm', like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<meetUpData>
    <location>3</location>
    <name>2</name>
    <sessionsData>
        <date>345</date>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <theme>Windows</theme>
    </sessionsData>
    <sessionsData>
        <date>3</date>
        <quantity>7</quantity>
        <theme>9</theme>
    </sessionsData>
</meetUpData>
```

Please provide your classes if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Woops, that's a typo right here, my xml document has one such line

Comment: Well, the error was that in this line of code
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MeetUp.class);
I should use this instead
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MeetUpData.class);
But I've got some another errors after that and your advice about "lower case of letters" helped me to deal with them, Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try only the last two lines:

```
meetUpData = (MeetUpData) ums.unmarshal(new FileInputStream("src\\com\\bases\\java\\InitialXML.xml"));
        System.out.println("Info: " + meetUpData.toString());
```